# adding non-data controls in nested silverlight datagrid

Tags: silverlight-3.0, datagrid

I am using nested silverlight datagrid. I am using RowdetailsTemplate to show 2nd level of datagrid. Once all the data in 2nd level of datagrid is shown, I want to add a stackpanel at bottom each row in second grid. This stackpanel will have some controls in it. Is there anyway I can acheive this?

```
<datagrid1>
  <row1>
    <datagrid2>
       <row1>
       <row2>
       <row3>
      <stackpanel>
    </datgrid2>   
  </row1>
  <row2>
    <datagrid2>
       <row1>
       <row2>
       <row3>
      <stackpanel>
    </datgrid2>   
  </row2>
</datgrid1>
```

Comment: Is there a limitation on the height of the outer rows such that the inner DataGrid needs to scroll or are you expecting the outer row to grow to accomodate all the content of inner datagrid plus extras?

Comment: I have set vertical scrollbar and maxHeight for outer datagrid. So when content grows beyond the extent, vertical scrollbar would appear.